# Making Json objects using Session Variables in another file

Tags: javascript, php, json, session, variables

I was trying to make a Json Object of some variables Which I am using as Session variables, But I am not geting the proper Response To make it as Json Object ..
Some Code which I tried (for Reference) Sharing Below..

```
//Passing the Variable To another PHP File
        session_start();
            $_SESSION['EmailIds']=$strEmailIds;
            $_SESSION['SCHOOL_NAME']=$SCHOOL_NAME;
//sending data to another php page ..
        header('Location: ../SecondPage.php');
```

In second file SecondPage.php Where i was Using This Session..

```
session_start();
$SCHOOL_NAME = $_SESSION['SCHOOL_NAME'];//1
$EmailIds= $_SESSION['EmailIds'];//1 <br>
```

Now trying to make this Session Variable in Json OBject...????

```
var OBJ = jsonObj.(SCHOOL_NAME+EmailIds);// Confuse with THis Line<br>
```

Actuaaly Not Getting What is the Good Approach To make this variables as Json Objects..
AS I Made this Json Object I can Use This AS another Purpose Like to send as Ajax Data and etc..

Comment: I have to make an Variable in JavaScript to send this data as ajax..

Comment: can some some tell me, How to make my one Variable as EMAIL ID Like a Clickable ... And Send this Email ID to another PHP File... ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **json_encode** method like this :

```
$someArray; //can be array of your values or $_SESSION
$jsonObj = json_encode($someArray);
```

Comment: You mean I have make an Array firstly than.. Convert It into the JavaScript Variable

Comment: no you dont have to use javascript variable json_encode is php mehod.
Refer this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thanks Bro... Got It...!!

Answer (score 0):

get session data in an array like :
$data['SCHOOL_NAME'] = $_SESSION['SCHOOL_NAME'];
$data['EmailIds']= $_SESSION['EmailIds'];

then encode it like 
$json_obj = json_encode($data);

Comment: Thanks For compliment .. :)